# How to update a custom composer package across many Github hosted projects?

Tags: github, composer-php

I've developed a composer package that's included into many Github repo Laravel projects. It's set to a specific version, but even if I make it slightly looser and set the patch version to be a asterisk for the patch version I still need to run a `composer update` in the project that requires the package so that when running `composer install` on a server it installs the correct version.

The issue I'm facing is that when I release a new package version, I've got to run `composer update` locally, say 15 times each for 15 projects, then commit all 15, and open pull requests for all 15 etc making the process incredibly slow.

Is there a better way to handle `composer update`, maybe I need to develop a little CLI application to communicate with the Github api to open PRs and merge them?

Comment: Yes, you need to do that in all projects seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is exactly what's expected and intended to happen. Full projects with commited lock-files are supposed to install the locked version unless updated.

You could use something like [this composer update action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/composer-update-action) to run regularly and create commits when necessary, or work with the GitHub provided [Dependabot](https://github.blog/2020-06-01-keep-all-your-packages-up-to-date-with-dependabot/).

But if this is not coupled with a robust test suite and finely tuned version constraints, you could end up breaking already working projects because some randome dependency introduced an unexpected change in behavior.